# How to use a different drawable res folder (for eg. drawable-theme1) when the appTheme is selected as "theme1" from styles.xml? Is this possible?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, android-theme, android-styles

Currently I am having four themes in my styles.xml file. (theme1, theme2, theme3, theme4).

I am having a **test_image.xml** in both **drawable** & **drawable-theme1** folders.

What I need is, for **theme1** alone, I need resources from **drawable-theme1**, and for other themes (theme2, theme3, theme4), I need resources from normal drawable folder.

Finally, while setting the image view programmatically, I will be calling *imageView.setResource(R.drawable.test_image)*. The resource file must be retrieved based on my selected theme.

Whether this is possible?

I could not get any questions or similar relevant to this. If anyone has provided a solution already, please help me finding that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** use `<themeName>` as a [**qualifier**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).
It means that you **can't** use a `drawable-themeName` folder.

However you can define a custom attribute in the `attrs.xml` file:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="myDrawable" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

Then in `styles.xml` in the app theme you can define it:

```
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <!-- .....   -->
    <item name="myDrawable">@drawable/ic_add_24px</item>

</style>
```

Finally in a layout you can use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    ....
    app:icon="?attr/myDrawable"/>
```

or programmatically:

```
    MaterialButton button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.myDrawable, typedValue, true);
    button.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,typedValue.resourceId));
```